# Dynamically compare objects of two differents classes based solely on commons properties

Tags: java, reflection

I'm writing some fully dynamic methods in which I need to compare two objects of different classes.

Here is an example of the objects :

```
public class Object1 {

    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private int age;
    private int gender;

    //All getters and setters
}

public class Object2 {

    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private String job;

    //All getters and setters

}
```

As you can see here, the only common property is lastname, so I want that my comparison applies only on lastname

In addition :

- In my real code, I use lots of different classes, I can't make them implements common interfaces, In fact, I can't modify them at all
- I don't know which could be the commons properties, so I can't hardcode my tests
- I'm using Java 8

So I'm looking for some class, similar to BeanUtils which has a copyProperties method for common properties, but here, instead of copying I'd like to compare.

I think this kind of utility class may exist, but I can't find one.

So if you have an idea, I'll be happy to read it :)

Thanks !

[Edit 1] More informations about why I want to do that :

I'm writing a generic system to generate endpoints for a REST Api based on JAX-RS (Jersey).
I'm using interfaces with generics types like this «simple» example :

```
public interface sampleEndpoint<BEANPARAM,BODYREQUEST,RESPONSE>  {

    @PUT
    @Path("/{id}")
    default RESPONSE update(@Valid @BeanParam BEANPARAM bp, @Valid BODYREQUEST body) {
        //Check if id in path is the same as id in the body

        ....
    }


}
```

(With Jersey we can't use BeanParam to retrieve in the same Bean PathParam, QueryParam and RequestBody... here is why I need to use both, BeanParam and another bean for the body)

My use cases may be more complex, but this one is a simple illustration.

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? You may wish to tell more about the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're trying to solve it as there's a possibility that your approach may be improved.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my message in order to add some explanations at the end

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather it seems that the [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) is exactly what you are looking for. You can get a list of all [Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.htm) in each class and then compare two Fields' values only if they have the same name.

The major benefit of this approach is that it can be generalized for any two classes. However, Reflection is often frowned upon because it breaks encapsulation and I would recommend that you look for a better solution specific to your problem before settling for this one.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiser Keister . Reflection is definitly the way to do that, but I thinks there already exists utility classes (using reflections) that make this, that was the purpose of my question.
(In parallel I'm still looking after another solution to my problem in order to avoid to have this use case, but it seems that at this time there's no way to mix PathParam/QueryParam and RequestBody in the same Bean. It is possible to write something that achieves this, but in this case, swagger doesn't work, and I need swagger too)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up to create my own class to achieve what I want.

I've decided to use jackson (fasterxml), to convert my object in JsonNode and then recursively compare the JsonNodes.

Here is the code (I need to do some tests to verify it more deeply, but it works for my use cases) :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class ObjectComparator {


    /**
     * For each attribute of «expected» Object, verify if this attribute exists in «actual» and if it exists, verify if the value is the same as the «expected» one
     *
     * @param expected : the reference JsonNode
     * @param actual : the Object in which we want to verify the attributes
     * @return true if all commons attributes between «expected» and «actual» have same values, otherwise returns false
     */
    public static boolean CommonsAttributesComparator(Object expected, Object actual) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode expectedNode = mapper.convertValue(expected, JsonNode.class);
        JsonNode actualNode = mapper.convertValue(actual, JsonNode.class);

        return(JsonNodeComparator(expectedNode, actualNode));
    }


    /**
     * For each attribute of «expected» JsonNode, verify if this attribute exists in «actual» and if it exists, verify if the value is the same as the «expected» one
     *
     * @param expectedNode : the reference JsonNode
     * @param actualNode : the JsonNode in which we want to verify the attributes
     * @return true if all commons attributes between «expected» and «actual» have same values, otherwise returns false
     */
    public static boolean JsonNodeComparator(JsonNode expectedNode, JsonNode actualNode) {

        Iterator<String> expectedKeys =  expectedNode.fieldNames();
        if(!expectedKeys.hasNext()) {
            return expectedNode.equals(actualNode);
        }
        while (expectedKeys.hasNext()) {
            String currentKey = expectedKeys.next();
            if (
                    !expectedNode.get(currentKey).isNull()
                            && actualNode.has(currentKey)
                            && !actualNode.get(currentKey).isNull()) {

                if (expectedNode.get(currentKey).isArray()) {
                    if (actualNode.get(currentKey).isArray()
                    && actualNode.get(currentKey).size() == expectedNode.get(currentKey).size()) {

                        boolean subNodeComparisonSucceeded = false;
                        for (final JsonNode expectedSubNode : expectedNode.get(currentKey)) {
                            for (final JsonNode actualSubNode : actualNode.get(currentKey)) {
                                subNodeComparisonSucceeded = JsonNodeComparator(expectedSubNode, actualSubNode);
                                if(subNodeComparisonSucceeded) {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if(!subNodeComparisonSucceeded) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(expectedNode.get(currentKey).size() > 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if(!expectedNode.get(currentKey).equals(actualNode.get(currentKey))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```